# A Scavenge of Songs

Tags: word, knowledge

I gathered a large group of people and told them to come early on a Saturday morning to try out something fun. They all arrived and were upset when they saw I had brought a huge bag of balloons instead. What did they shout out to me in anger? (4)

Here's a few songs that have been completely re-titled. Find the correct songs and use the artists to help you find the one that answers the above.

> Think confectionary thoughts unconsciously (2)
>   Let's roll down in a ball (1)
>   I can hear your interest and awe (1)
>   A specific patch of green (2)
>   When life gives you cola (2)
>   Is it possible for me to take a brief piece of time and stay (7)
>   Shalom Earth! (4)
>   Delusion of a sergeant's note (4)

I created this with what the US Spotify had available, but Spotify isn't necessary to solve it. It would make the searching much easier though.

**Hint 1**

> They have been *completely* retitled, so none of the words in each line are in the title they are referring to. I tried to make the hints as exact as possible, and to represent songs that shouldn't have any other with that name (unless it's a cover song)

**Hint 2**

> As I mentioned in a comment below, for line 4, "specific" is referring to the word "The" which is part of the answer. If it referenced a park, that would make it really ambiguous so that's not the route to go down.

**Hint 3**

> Alternate, Alternate lyrics for the ones left
>
> -Literally get inside a ball and roll down a hill (1)
> -Almost a backwards owl (1)
> -A rolling stone’s loss (2)
> -A sour fizzy beverage (2)
> -Made 2 edits to the original line (7) …really hard to retitle this one again without using any of the words. A hint for one of the words “menthe mother”.
> -Adios Venus (4)
> -Within a large Bee’s Psychosis(4)

**Hint 4**

> Two of the hints aren't in the correct order of the actual title. (If I did, they would become nonsensical)

Comment: When life gives ME a cola, I prefer a Pork Soda from Primus.  Though it isn't sour.

Comment: @B540Glenn Pork Soda sounds really gross to ME, but it's cool if you're into that sorta thing

Comment: Just to confirm, do the numbers in brackets correspond to the number of words in the song title?

Comment: @hexomino yeah they do!

Answer (score 5):

Unconscious Confectionary:

> "Sweet Dreams" by Eurythmics (or by Marilyn Manson etc...)

Interest and Awe

> "OMG" by Usher & Will.i.am

or

> "Smooth" by Santanna

A specific patch of green

> "MacArthur Park" by Glen Campbell

or a more famous location by a less famous band

> "Hyde Park" by "Tangerine Dream"

Comment: "hear" I'm looking more for a noise, and I can see how a specific patch of green might lead you towards that sort of answer. I'll go ahead and say that "specific" was meaning "The". I was unsure how to get that across any other way. Also focus on "patch" it's normally used in conjunction with the other word I'm looking for.

Comment: There is a "song" called |"Gasp" but I don't think that's the one.  it seems to be related to some Australian children's TV show.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't fit quite right either

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can start to put something together...

Think confectionary thoughts unconsciously (2)

> Sweet Dreams by the Eurythmics (thanks, @jasen!)

Let's roll down in a ball (1)

> Zorbing by Stornoway?

I can hear your interest and awe (1)

> 

A specific patch of green (2)

> The Moss by Cosmo Sheldrake?

When life gives you cola (2)

> Lemon Soda by NGC 3.14 x Tenkitsune? or Lemon Cola by DAWN (thanks, @hagfy)?

Is it possible for me to take a brief piece of time and stay (7)

> Not sure, but menthe mother -> mom mint, ie. moment (thanks, @hexomino!)

Shalom Earth! (4)

> Goodbye to a World by Porter Robinson (thanks, @hagfy!)

Delusion of a sergeant's note (4)

> 

Comment: Could it be "mom mint" -> moment?

Comment: Ooh this is good

Comment: Nicely put together so far! Your first guesses for 1, 2, 4, 5 and 7 are correct. And good idea @hexomino ;)

Answer (score 2):

Correct:

Shalom Earth! (4)

> "Goodbye to a World" by Porter Robinson

---

New guess:

I can hear your interest and awe (1)

> "Cheers" by Rihanna?  Or the Cheers theme song by Gary Portnoy and Judy Hart Angelo?
> You can hear interest/awed people cheer for you
> Also, adding a 'c' between r-s and swapping the first two letters gives you 'screech' backwards (a type of owl)

Comment: Your second one is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I can hear your interest and awe (1)

> Wow by Beck?

Comment: Can you please add an explanation?

Comment: Wow is a common expression to show interest (wow, tell me more) or awe (wow, look at that)

Comment: Good guess, but not the word I was looking for. I would have worded it differently to better fit that word if so. Wow would be better fit for "I can hear your surprise and amazement". But still, good guess